# Get contenteditable value by PHP POST

Tags: php, html

I create own WYSIWYG and I want to get his content (its `div`)

I try to do this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="editor"]');
$_POST['details'] = $divContent;
```

```html
<div id="editor" style='height:500px;' name="details" contenteditable required>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to get the div that have the id `editor` content, but its return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Now you find div with item `id`. To select attribute use `@`

```
 $divContent = $xpath->query('//div[@id="editor"]');
```

To get outterHTML of `div`

```
 echo $dom->saveHTML($divContent->item(0));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a091b33e6c3d858b594e2cd81e0b8d23b469c800)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b6f30709f49a26d65b58cd79630852d3fe59162

Comment: I see its work but my `$html` need to be all the page content (the content changed by user) and not default.

Comment: @Dasmond - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9ec37ac05b4d62d8053354430ac9cc384c6a320

Comment: @Dasmond You can put any fragment of your html there  to test

Comment: I know my friend but the page content changed dynamiclly.. I mean, the `editor` content changed by user..

Comment: That code is independent of div content. It select div with attribute `id=editor`

Comment: I know but you put a variable name `$html` in the top that have a static content.. my html changed dynamiclly

Comment: Have you tried to set $html as you want ? It will work not only with that source data